# How do I show 6 product from every main category on the front page?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, products, custom, frontend

I want to list 6 products from every main category on the front page of my Magento (1.9) shop.

Here's a great example of what I would like it to look like:

[image]

How could I achieve this?

Comment: put this collection code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the top categories.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2) //top level...yeah I know it says 2 but it's top level. believe me.
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1); //only active categories.
```

Here is how you can get 6 products from a category

```
//assuming that $category is the category instance you need  
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category) //filter by category
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add the minimum needed attribtues
    ->addMinimalPrice() //add all kind of prices
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents()
    ->addUrlRewrite($category->getId()) //url rewrite with category path
    ->setPage(1, 6); //limit: page 1, limit 6
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection); //only enabled products
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection); //only visible products
```

Here is how you can add a block to the homepage.
Edit the homepage in CMS->Pages and add this to the content.

```
{{block type="block/type_here" template="path/to/template/here.phtml"}}
```

Now you need to create the template `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/path/to/template/here.phtml` where you place the content of your html file.

You also need a custom block that will hold the logic of the block That block alias should be placed where it states `block/type_here`.
If you don't want to create a block you can use `core/template` instead of `block/type_here` but this means you have to put all the logic in the template.
Not the best way to do it, but I won't tell anyone.

You have all the facts. All you need it to put them together.
Good luck.

For the actual html you should seek inspiration in the product list pages.

Comment: Great answer. Are you interested in doing this for me? (paid)

Comment: I almost did it, here, for free. Sorry but I don't have the time to do it because I'm wasting too much time on SE :).